# apparmor profile for libreoffice in a ubuntu snap package

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, apparmor

I have libreoffice installed as a snap and it's printing subsystem isn't working because of the apparmor permissions. The syslog shows the following:

```
May 25 08:18:15 chrome kernel: [44272.687192] audit: type=1400 audit(1495693095.846:124): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" name="/run/cups/cups.sock" pid=16873 comm=435550534D616E6167657220637570 requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 25 08:18:25 chrome kernel: [44282.828587] audit: type=1400 audit(1495693105.990:125): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" name="/run/cups/cups.sock" pid=16873 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

I've already posted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1684014) but still got no reply. So basically I need a workaround for this. I've created a profile:

```
$ cat /etc/apparmor.d/snap.libreoffice.19.usr.local.lib.libreoffice.program.soffice.bin 
# vim:syntax=apparmor
#include <tunables/global>

/snap/libreoffice/19/usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/cups-client>

}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What did I do wrong? Any apparmor experts here?